# Python pandas check if dataframe is not empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an `if` statement where it checks if the data frame is not empty. The way I do it is the following:

```
if dataframe.empty:
    pass
else:
    #do something
```

But really I need:

```
if dataframe is not empty:
    #do something
```

My question is - is there a method `.not_empty()` to achieve this? I also wanted to ask if the second version is better in terms of performance? Otherwise maybe it makes sense for me to leave it as it is i.e. the first version?

Comment: Why can't you do `not dataframe.empty`?

Comment: `not df.empty` or a faster `len(df.index)` check?

Comment: @Zero, can anyone speak to the preferability of `len(df.index)` vs `df.empty`? pylint prefers the latter, but do performance considerations outweigh the stylistic benefit (if it exists)?

Answer (score 175):

Just do

```
if not dataframe.empty:
     # insert code here
```

The reason this works is because `dataframe.empty` returns `True` if dataframe is empty. To invert this, we can use the negation operator `not`, which flips `True` to `False` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 19):

.empty returns a boolean value

```
>>> df_empty.empty
True
```

So if not empty can be written as

```
if not df.empty:
    #Your code
```

Check [pandas.DataFrame.empty](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) 
, might help someone.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the attribute `dataframe.empty` to check whether it's empty or not:

```
if not dataframe.empty:
    #do something
```

Or

```
if len(dataframe) != 0:
   #do something
```

Or

```
if len(dataframe.index) != 0:
   #do something
```

Comment: or just `if len(dataframe):`

Comment: What about `if len(dataframe) != 0:`?

Comment: Might add **if df.shape[0]** also

Answer (score 3):

As already clearly explained by other commentators, you can negate a boolean expression in Python by simply prepending the *not* operator, hence:

```
if not df.empty:
  # do something
```

does the trick.

I only want to clarify the meaning of "empty" in this context, because it was a bit confusing for me at first.

According to the Pandas documentation, the [DataFrame.empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) method returns *True* if **any** of the axes in the DataFrame are of length 0.

As a consequence, "empty" doesn't mean zero rows **and** zero columns, like someone might expect. A dataframe with zero rows (axis 1 is empty) but non-zero columns (axis 2 is not empty) is still considered empty:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"])
> df.empty
True
```

Another interesting point highlighted in the documentation is a DataFrame that only contains NaNs is **not** considered empty.

```
> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B", "C"], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
> df
     A    B    C
a  NaN  NaN  NaN
b  NaN  NaN  NaN
c  NaN  NaN  NaN
> df.empty
False
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way:

```
if dataframe.empty == False:
    #do something`
```

Comment: Checking boolean values like this is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.